# What Would Cause A Form To Freeze Upon Executing Code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process, waitforexit

I'm trying to figure why my form freezes up when executing some code. I also can't minimize or move the form. Is it because of the `WaitForExit` being used in the process?

The below code is tied to a button click.

```
If Checkbox1.checked = True Then
   Call Test()
End If

If Checkbox2.checked = True Then
   Goto NextStep
Else
   Goto StopProcessing
End If
```

Here is the test sub I'm calling. Calls an exe with an optional argument.

```
        Using psinfo As New Process
            psinfo.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Temp\Test.exe "
            psinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg1
            psinfo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            psinfo.Start()
            psinfo.WaitForExit()
        End Using
```

The `WaitForExit` was added (so I thought) to not process the next statement (next statement being the If statement for Checkbox2) until the process was complete. Is this not the case?

Comment: I'm not quite clear about what you're asking, but yes, WaitForExit() will stop your execution cold until the process exits.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Alright, well thanks, back to the drawing board I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The WaitForExit was added (so I thought) to not process the next statement (next statement being the If statement for Checkbox2) until the process was complete.

When you call `WaitForExit`, it will block until the process (`Test.exe`) completes.

Since you're running this on the user interface thread, it will cause your form to "freeze" until the process completes fully.

If you need this to not occur, you would need to wait on a background thread.  You could, potentially, move this code into a `BackgroundWorker` and use it to synchronize with your main window - but you will need to handle "waiting" for the process to finish in a different manner (ie: disable your UI up front, run the process, re-enable when complete).

Note that, with the Process class, another alternative would be to add `EnableRaisingEvents` on the process, then adding a handler to [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx).  This will let you not `WaitForExit()`, but instead get notified via an event when the process completes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had a feeling by using the `WaitForExit` that in turn it was locking up the interface. I'll take a look at your suggestions, thanks again.

Comment: One quick question, does it make sense to have more than one backgroundworker? IE for each process I have?

Comment: @Muhnamana Depending on what you're doing, the event approach is likely better.  If you're going to be running the processes at the same time, then >1 BW makes sense.  If you want to run them one at a time, then a single makes more sense.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I have a grasp on the approach I need. Thanks again!